# Typescript limitation workaround

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming

I have a code, that is totaly OK from the human perspective. But it looks like typescript type system have hard time to understand it. **Is there a smart way to hint compiler that everything is fine in that line**?

```
  const isMustToRun: boolean = isFunc(condition) ? condition() : condition;
```

code:

```
    export const noop = function() {
    };

    export const isFunc = function(obj: any): boolean {
      return typeof obj === 'function';
    };

    /**
     *
     * @param func funtion to run
     * @param condition condition check
     * @param args
     */
    export const runIf = function f(condition: (Function | boolean), func: Function, ...args: any[]) {
      return () => {
        const isMustToRun: boolean = isFunc(condition) ? condition() : condition;
        return isMustToRun ? func(...args) : noop();
      };
    };
```

If I wrote

```
typeof condition === 'function'
```

instead of "isFunc" call, then it works. But I don't want to repeat the code..

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Your type declaration for the parameter does not include the return value type.

Comment: @Pointy Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'boolean | Function' has no compatible call signatures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the return type of

```
export const isFunc = function(obj: any): boolean {
  return typeof obj === 'function';
};
```

to be `is Function`

```
export const isFunc = function(obj: any): obj is Function {
  return typeof obj === 'function';
};
```

## More

This is called a [user defined type guard](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html)

Comment: That what I wanted. Thank you for pointing me to documentation :-)

Comment: Also note that `typeof condition === 'function' ? condition() : condition` would compile, as TS understands the `typeof` type-guard.

Answer (score 2):

You need to transform `isFunc` in a custom type guard and your code will work as expected.:

```
export const isFunc = function(obj: any): obj is Function {
  return typeof obj === 'function';
};
```

I would recommend not using `Function` though as it is not really very type safe, you can tighten up the function type with a function signature, and use the `Extract` conditional type to preserve the actual type of the passed in function to the `isFunc` type-guard:

```
export const isFunc = function<T>(obj: T): obj is Extract<T, Function> {
    return typeof obj === 'function';
};

export const runIf = function f(condition: ((()=> boolean) | boolean), func: Function, ...args: any[]) {
    return () => {
        const isMustToRun: boolean = isFunc(condition) ? condition() : condition;
        return isMustToRun ? func(...args) : noop();
     };
};
```

Or a fully type safe version of `runIf` that checks the `args` agains the `func` parameters:

```
export const runIf = function f<T extends (...a: any)=>any>(condition: ((()=> boolean) | boolean), func: T, ...args: Parameters<T>): (()=>ReturnType<T>) {
    return () => {
    const isMustToRun: boolean = isFunc(condition) ? condition() : condition;
        return isMustToRun ? func(...args as any[]) : noop();
    };
};

function testFn(n: string) : number { return +n;}
runIf(true, testFn, "0"); //ok
runIf(true, testFn, 0); //err
```

Comment: It's not necessary to narrow it down. TypeScript will not widen the type to `Function`. The original definition will be preserved. Try running your first answer against `declare const foo: typeof addEventListener | null; if (isFunc(foo)) foo()`.